# Android - цвет полосы у ProgressBar

Tags: xml, android, java, progress-bar

Здравствуйте! Есть идентичный код шести горизонтальных ProgressBar'ов:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/clmt_1"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp" />
```

Как можно изменить цвет полосы прогресса, не создавая дополнительные (6 штук) xml-файлы? То есть код всех ProgressBar'ов будет одинаковый, но будут только различия в цвете полосы.

Заранее спасибо за помощь.